# Firefox always opens behind calling program

Tags: rhel, firefox, html

I am opening a local html file with Firefox on RHEL 6.3 with Gnome 2.28.2 and Metacity 2.28.0. Unfortunately, regardless of how I open it (terminal or java) Firefox always opens in the background, behind the application which called it.

Is there a way to force applications to start in the foreground? Perhaps something similar to the "&" parameter which opens applications in the background?

Comment: FYI, "foreground" and "background" for your *window manager* is a different concept than "foreground" and "background" for a *shell*. The `&` operator only has meaning in a shell environment and has nothing to do with windowing.